# Force GVim to prompt before close

Tags: vim

I've been making a transition to GVim lately, because I find it to be more aesthetically pleasing and a little bit faster then vim in the terminal. I have this really bad habit that I'm trying to break. When I used vim from the command line my work flow was like this:

```
vim filename.txt
# make some edits
ZZ
# do other stuff
vim otherfile.txt
# make some edits
ZZ
```

Now using GVim, I end up closing the editor far too frequently. I'm wondering if there is a way to force just GVim to either prompt me or open an empty buffer when I do a `:wq` or `ZZ`. Any ideas?

EDIT: I know how to remap keys, but I'm wondering if there is a way to force GVim to have a different behavior then when vim is called from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call a function on `ZZ` and if there is only one tab and window left, prompt whether to close or not (default is to close). See `:help confirm()`.

```
nnoremap ZZ :call QuitPrompt()<cr>

fun! QuitPrompt()
   if has("gui_running") && tabpagenr("$") == 1 && winnr("$") == 1
      let choice = confirm("Close?", "&yes\n&no", 1)
      if choice == 1 | wq | endif
   else | wq | endif
endfun
```

Answer (score 6):

Putting the following in your vimrc could be used to completely disable the ZZ shortcut altogether:

```
nnoremap ZZ   <Nop>
```

Or you could remap them to the standard behaviour of `:q` :

```
if has("gui_running")
    nnoremap ZZ :q
    nnoremap :wq :q
endif
```

Comment: I can do that, but I still like the ability to bring up vim in the command line, do a quick edit and ZZ.

Comment: If that's the case, just surround it with `if has("gui_running")...endif`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your .vimrc:

```
set confirm
```

Answer (score 0):

Gvim and vim handle quit a little differently.  Option 1 works as you would expect in both.  Option 2 works nice in vim, but in gvim you can get around it (in part) by pressing the "X" to close in X Windows. It will still confirm if the file is unedited, but it will just quit everything when everything is saved.  Maybe someone else knows how to deal with that issue.

**Option 1: Confirm quit only when a file is unsaved**

Add this in your .vimrc:

```
set confirm
```

**Option 2: Confirm quit all the time (when you do ZZ or q)**

Use this plugin

```
 Plugin 'vim-scripts/confirm-quit'
```

Or hand code it, [following along with this to see what you need to do](https://github.com/vim-scripts/confirm-quit/blob/master/plugin/confirm_quit.vim) (BTW -- this plugin was born from [this SE Question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/how-do-i-avoid-exiting-vim-to-open-a-new-file/3712#3712))