# Does vi support "confirm on quit"

Tags: vim, editor

When typing fast, I sometimes accidentally type :wq, when in fact I just wanted to :w. Obviously, this causes a major pain when I have a session with numerous files and I end up losing all my buffers and have to reopen those files one after another in a new session. Just wondering if vim supports a "confirm on quit" feature that can prevent me from shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force GVim to prompt before close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672028/force-gvim-to-prompt-before-close)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+confirm+quit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556267/how-to-prevent-quitting-vim-accidentally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy solution: put `set confirm` in your vimrc. If you want more customization, consider writing function like in this plugin: https://github.com/vim-scripts/confirm-quit/tree/master/plugin